# Kubernetes Ingress failing to get address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am trying to set up an ingress for services using nginx ingress on AWS EKS.

I have installed nginx ingress with the code provided on [Kubernetes' github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/deploy/static/provider/aws/1.23/deploy.yaml) page.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
automountServiceAccountToken: true
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - pods
  - secrets
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - ingress-controller-leader
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - create
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - admissionregistration.k8s.io
  resources:
  - validatingwebhookconfigurations
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https-webhook
    port: 443
    targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: LD_PRELOAD
          value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
        image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.2.0@sha256:d8196e3bc1e72547c5dec66d6556c0ff92a23f6d0919b206be170bc90d5f9185
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /wait-shutdown
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 90Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
          name: webhook-cert
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
      - name: webhook-cert
        secret:
          secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - create
        - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
        - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: create
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - patch
        - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        - --patch-mutating=false
        - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.1.1@sha256:64d8c73dca984af206adf9d6d7e46aa550362b1d7a01f3a0a91b20cc67868660
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: patch
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
webhooks:
- admissionReviewVersions:
  - v1
  clientConfig:
    service:
      name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      path: /networking/v1/ingresses
  failurePolicy: Fail
  matchPolicy: Equivalent
  name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - networking.k8s.io
    apiVersions:
    - v1
    operations:
    - CREATE
    - UPDATE
    resources:
    - ingresses
  sideEffects: None
```

It seems that I was able to create the ingress controller successfully.
[Image of ingress controller success.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mai4m.png)
I have created the deployment and service for the application that I want to deploy on the cluster via yaml like this

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: evcloud 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: evcloud-vertx
  namespace: evcloud
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: evcloud-tcp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: evcloud-tcp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: evcloud-tcp
          image: location of ecr container
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2238
            - containerPort: 2237
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: evcloud-tcp
  namespace: evcloud
spec:
  selector:
    app: evcloud-tcp
  ports:
  - port: 2238
    name: remote
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2238
  - port: 2237
    name: central
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2237
```

It seems that the pods and services have been deployed successfully.
[Image of pod running successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV2Ov.png)

I have tried to connect the service of these pods using an ingress via the yaml file below.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: evcloud
  namespace: evcloud
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ingress-nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: evcloud-tcp
            port: 
              number: 2237
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: evcloud-tcp
            port: 
              number: 2238
```

I was able to successfully make the ingress but the address seems to be empty.
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmyWl.png)

I am really new to Kubernetes, so any sort of feedback would be deeply appreciated!
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause because they were in different namespaces.
Solved it by using a headless service with externalName.